# Create Video Capture / Screencast using Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, video-capture

Is it possible to create create a video capture / screencast using Adobe Flex?

I would like to record any part of the users desktop (the web browser, the OS desktop, etc.) at a reasonable frame rate, record from the microphone, and then create a video file.

I would prefer doing this via Flex rather than using Java (Ex: [Screencast-o-matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/)) or using a Windows App (Ex: [Camtasia Recorder](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/))

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this via the browser or a Flex-only AIR app.  You can only capture things that are within the application's window.  Additionally you cannot capture anything beneath the window.  So if you made your window 99% transparent and captured that you would not capture any underlying windows or the desktop.

AIR 2 has a NativeProcesses API that you could use to accomplish this.  [gotoandlearn.com](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=125) has a tutorial for creating screenshots that could probably be expanded into video capture.  The trade-off is that you're not making a pure Flex app anymore.  Also this only works for AIR and not in the browser.